# Как записать в переменную типа QString или string вывод stdout?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Программа вызывает функцию, которая выводит в `FILE*` результат работы. Вызов функции выглядит таким образом:

```
gvRender (gvc, g, "svg", stdout);
```

Необходимо перенаправить вывод из `stdout` в `string` или `QString`, не используя запись в файл. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Возможно, `QProcess`?

Comment: В случае с библиотекой graphviz,  в которой функции начинаются с <gv>, оказалось, что есть отдельная функция, отправляющая результат в стрингу. Это gvRenderData()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно использовать переназначение потоковых буферов. <kbd>[Пример:](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Oh7LybRw30qF6XTd)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    auto cout_buff = std::cout.rdbuf(); // сохраняем родной буфер cout
    std::cout.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf()); // перенаправляем вывод в строковой поток
    std::cout << "hello\n";  // реально печатает в строку (на экране ещё пусто)
    std::cout.rdbuf(cout_buff); // возвращаем родной буфер
    std::cout << ss.str(); // выводим содержимое строки
}
```

---

Если нужно переназначить сишный `stdout` в другой файл, то можно использовать [`freopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/). Некоторые варианты можно почерпнуть из [вопроса на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955962/how-to-buffer-stdout-in-memory-and-write-it-from-a-dedicated-thread).

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает

Comment: Объясните, зачем, если в Qt есть нативные средства?

Comment: @PinkTux нативные для чего?

Comment: @alexolut, для Qt :) В одном направлении я ткнул в комменте к вопросу.  По нему моментально можно выйти и на второе: QTextStream.

Comment: @PinkTux так напишите ответ что ли. :)

Comment: @alexolut, мне откровенно лень писать ответы, вся суть которых сводится к "докумениацию читать пробовали?" или "первый же клик в гугле". к тому же это принижает умственные способности задавшего вопрос. впрочем, если он не среагировал на коммент, оставленный через несколько минут после размещения вопроса, а предпочёл ждать несколько часов пока не разжуют и в рот положат...

Comment: @PinkTux правильно ли я понял, что QTextStream позволит перехватить например вывод printf?

Comment: @alexolut, оно делает ровно то же самое, что вы написали в духе std. Но - контекст важен в любом случае :)